# Define a function in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado

Hi all I have this main in Tornado:

```
def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    periodic = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(check_commands_response, 5000)
    periodic.start()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Now, how you can see, I've put in the main a periodic function that calls a function.

In this function I would use some function methods that are into some classes.... so I cannot put this check_commands_response out of the class. But I can't put the function also into the class (it's a BaseHandler) because when the main starts the function isn't already defined...

How can I do?

**EDIT**

What is wrong if I write this:

```
class CheckCommandResponse(BaseHandler):
    @tornado.web.authenticated
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.engine

    @staticmethod
    def check_commands_response(self):
        self.lock_tables("read", ['networks'])
        nets = self.db.query("SELECT DISTINCT netid from networks")
        self.unlock_tables

        for net in nets:
            got_commands_response(net)

    @staticmethod
    def got_commands_response(netid):
        como_url = "".join("http://xx.xx.xx.xx:44444/ztc_config?netid=" \
                   + netid + "&opcode_group=0&opcode=0&start=-10s&end=-1s")

        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        #asynchronous alternative to time.sleep
        yield tornado.gen.Task(tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().add_timeout, time.time() + 5)
        response = yield tornado.gen.Task(http_client.fetch, como_url)

        print response




################################################################################
# Application Entry Point
################################################################################
def main():
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(Application())
    http_server.listen(options.port)
    periodic = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(CheckCommandResponse.check_commands_response, 5000)
    periodic.start()
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Can we see a snippet of the check_commands_response?

Comment: @sharkbait I think more information is needed. You're a little imprecise with your wording so I am not sure what's going on -- but it sounds like you want check_commands_response to use some object which doesn't exist yet during main(). If you could clarify that would be helpful.

Comment: yes sorry it's this @OEP . The function is still unwritten, but I have to use into this some methods that are defined in the BaseHandler class, that is a class base for all the other handlers of the server.

So I don't know how to put a function that use methods of a class, but that is called into the main.... It's this possible?

Comment: See my edits to the question

Comment: @sharkbait This looks like kind of an odd design to me. I'll preface my comment with that I don't know much about the tornado framework, but it looks like handlers are what respond to web requests. It looks, however, like your handler is trying to make requests itself. Also, I find your use of the 'yield' keyword confusing. Perhaps you can give the intention of these methods and it will clear up what the best design would be.

Comment: BTW, if you simply want to call the method the way you have shown in your example, you should decorate check_command_response with either \@staticmethod or \@classmethod depending on what's appropriate. I will say though I think a better design is in order because check_command_response depends on 'self' and both \@staticmethod and \@classmethod disallow the calling of instance methods.

Comment: I've tried with these decorators but Tornado doesn't start... see the edit. I have to create an instance of the class in the main???